# How can I display progress bar as table row background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
th1    th2    th3    th4    th5    th6
td1    td2    td3    td4    td5    td6
td1    td2    td3    td4    td5    td6
```

New table rows are added with a form above that runs a background process to calculate all the data in each `td`. The process can take 10-60 seconds.

Rather than a separate column that displays progress, I'd like to shade the background of the entire `tr` as it corresponds to the % completion of the calculation process.

For example:

```
th1    th2    th3    th4    th5    th6
$ 1    $ 2    $ 3    $ 4    $ 5    $ 6   [100% done, 100% of row shaded light green]
$ -    $ -    $ -    $ -    $ -    $ -   [ 40% done,  40% of row shaded light green]
```

Background only:

```
th1    th2    th3    th4    th5    th6
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||   [100% done, 100% of row shaded light green]
|||||||||||||||                          [ 40% done,  40% of row shaded light green]
|||||||||                                [ 25% done,  25% of row shaded light green]
||||                                     [ 10% done,  10% of row shaded light green]
```

What do you recommend?

Here's some general markup:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>th1</th><th>th2</th><th>th3</th><th>th4</th><th>th5</th><th>th6</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-progress="100"><td>$1</td><td>$2</td><td>$3</td><td>$4</td><td>$5</td><td>$6</td></tr>
        <tr data-progress="40"><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
        <tr data-progress="25"><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
        <tr data-progress="10"><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I assume JS and CSS. I'm not sure how to tackle this yet. I just know ultimately I want the row itself to communicate progress rather than a separate progress section.

Comment: Hey, what's with the votes to close & downvotes? At least make a suggestion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For my solution you need an extra div in the first `td` of each `tr` but it looks pretty cool. Still needs some improvements but you get the idea...

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/CBJjv/2/

Call this function after updating `data-progress` values.

```
var updateProgress = function () {
    var trs = document.querySelectorAll('.table-body tr');
    for (var i=0; i<trs.length; i++) {
        var tr = trs[i];
        var pr = tr.querySelector('.progress');
        pr.style.left = (tr.dataset.progress - 100)+'%';
        pr.style.height = tr.clientHeight + 'px';
    }
}
```

Instead of playing with the position, you could also have a fixed position and modify the width of the `div`

Works in Chrome, not tested in other browsers.

Comment: Top notch work Pedro! Thanks. I tested it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari — all worked to some degree. Safari was choppy, no transitions. And Firefox wouldn't respect `overflow:hidden`, even on the `tr` as well.  Here's my update for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/CBJjv/3/  Thanks again. The overflow hidden thing is concerning. I'll look into it.

Comment: Then play with the width :) Maybe in safari you can have transitions using the webkit- prefix

Comment: hours saver :) liked the idea thanks

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is still looking for an elegant solution, you can style your `tr`. For a progress bar of 40%, I'd use:

`<tr style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right,lightgrey 40%,white 40%)">`

Example: https://codepen.io/drspa44/pen/rYEzWj

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Does not work in Safari 14.X. It repeats for every td.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that putting a background image on the tr is the way to go. However, you will need to change the display of the tr, and **background percentages do not work the way you expect**. Avoid using % in your background image position and just use px. You can calculate the width of your table, take your percentage and convert to px.

```
td { 
    display: block; 
    background: transparent url(shade-of-grey.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 0; 
}
```